# Firebase functions now timeout

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I read other SO posts regarding FIR timeouts and some of them were due to an update to `firebase-functions` or `firebase-admin`. I updated to the latest versions and even downgraded back to the original versions that worked (git checkout).

None of this worked.

I receive the `Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'` error for any of my FIR functions (while the requests work in Postman)

Sample code:

```
 exports.BSGetRequest = functions.https.onCall((url, context) => {
        console.log(url);

        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            uri: url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'MY_PRIVATE_KEY'
            },
            json: true
        };

        return rp(options)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log({ response });
                return repos;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error({ err });
                return err
            });
    });
```

I suspect it started to happen when Firebase Functions UI also changed (in the console; I think there was an major update) or my syntax doesn't keep up with Node 6.

UPDATE:

FIR functions started working again, but I didn't change anything. Case closed. I expect that it was something regarding my paid plan subscription.

Comment: You should probably switch to a Promise based solution, like [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait).  It could be that because you aren't returning promises, your function is timing out.

Comment: Erm, I might not have indented the code well. But I do return a Promise and this function did work before "the update" or whatever happened.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you need to return a promise from inside the promise.

Comment: I second @JamesPoag. Take a look at `request-promise`.

Comment: I switched to `request-promise`. The error still bugs me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATED error message could be getting thrown because `response` isn't an object and doesn't have a `body` property.

There could be some message in the `error` variable that you're not checking.

I've broken up your code a little bit with some comments and debugging which should help you get to the bottom of things.

The request will be timing out because it's throwing and error and not returning a rejection or response through the `promise`.

```
exports.BSGetRequest = functions.https.onCall((url, context) => {
  const options = {
      url: url,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'MY_PRIVATE_KEY'
      },
      json: true
  };

  return new Promise(function (fullfilled, rejected) {
    request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
        const decoded = he.decode(JSON.stringify(response.body));

        if (!error && response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 300) {
            fullfilled(JSON.parse(decoded));
            return;
        }

        // What's in `error`?
        console.error({ error });

        // I'm guessing this is where the error is - What's in `response` - Is there a `body`?
        console.log({ response });

        const responseErrorMessage = he.decode(JSON.stringify(response.body));

        const responseError = new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', responseErrorMessage);

        rejected(responseError);
    })
  });
});
```

EDIT: Try throwing the error message;

```
exports.BSGetRequest = functions.https.onCall((url, context) => {
  const options = {
      url: url,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'MY_PRIVATE_KEY'
      },
      json: true
  };

  return new Promise(function (fullfilled, rejected) {
    request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
        const decoded = he.decode(JSON.stringify(response.body));

        if (!error && response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 300) {
            fullfilled(JSON.parse(decoded));
            return;
        }

        // This should handle your error correctly.
        if (error) {
          const throwError = new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', error);

          rejected(throwError);
          return;
        }

        const responseErrorMessage = he.decode(JSON.stringify(response.body));

        const responseError = new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', responseErrorMessage);

        rejected(responseError);
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you on a free plan? You need to be on a paid version to access external domains.

Comment: Also try throwing the error instead of `response.body`.

Comment: I changed the code to ‘request-promise’. I also updated the answer: I am not on a Basic / Free plan.

Comment: Take a look at the URL you're trying to request, it might be timing out, the code all looks correct.

Comment: The function really does work (when I run it from `firebase:shell`), but it seems that it doesn't run from FIR servers. It's freaking annoying.